# Using Qt Creator to Cross Compilation for Non-Qt Projects

Tags: qt, qmake

I use qt creator for cross compilation non-qt projects.But I built qt-everywhere for arm to generate qmake because I couldn't use default qmake(for Desktop) for arm.
Is there any way cross compiling non-qt project without building qt-everywhere?

Comment: You could build just qmake - but qmake you do need.

Comment: How can I build only qmake?

Comment: Skip the `make` and `make install` steps. Only run the `configure` script. After that one is done, qmake has already been created. You can then simply copy it from the build folder. Theoretically you can even abort the configure script after qmake was created, as it outputs when it is done with that.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know qmake has already been generated after executing configure script

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you built Qt to develop on and target the ARM, not develop on a Host and target the ARM board. Building Qt to develop on the ARM will create qmake and other tools for the ARM. Building Qt to develop on the Host and target (run) on the arm will create the Qt build tools for the Host and the Qt runtimes for the ARM.

The secret is to add `-hostprefix <hostdir>` to the configure line. This specifies where to place the host side build tools (moc, uic, qmake) on the Host.

You can find a complete list of the options for `configure` by running `configure --help`.

Comment: No. I develop on host not target.